# No session factory registered for the given session options: {target: "master" config: }？

Tags: tensorflow

Look at my code:

```
def SessionManager_restore_test():
    '''
        In the model_ckpt/slim_train_init_fn_test.ckpt,
        {'x/y': 1.0, 'x/z': 2.0, 'y/z': 3.0}
    '''
    x_y = slim.variable('x/y', initializer=4.0)
    x_z = slim.variable('x/z', initializer=5.0)
    y_z = slim.variable('y/z', initializer=6.0)
    sm = tf.train.SessionManager()
    sess = sm.prepare_session(master='',
                              checkpoint_filename_with_path='model_ckpt/slim_train_init_fn_test.ckpt',
                              saver=tf.train.Saver())
    _x_y, _x_z, _y_z = sess.run([x_y, x_z, y_z])
    print(_x_y, _x_z, _y_z)
```

If I change master from '' to 'master', it will raise an error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: No session factory regist
ered for the given session options: {target: "master" config: } Registered facto
ries are {DIRECT_SESSION, GRPC_SESSION}.
```

Is which step missing? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify manually the master, you can do it by specifying its address, e.g.:

```
config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(master='grpc://localhost:2222',...)
```